# How to use multiplayer over Bluetooth

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition, ios

I have seen videos that say that you can use other apps that have a Bluetooth connection to play, but I guess it doesn't work on iOS 9. Is there any way to use local multiplayer over Bluetooth?

Answer (score -1):

2 players max per server.

1. Get any game which supports Bluetooth multiplayer eg Lightbike 2 (because it holds 4 people).
2. Enable Bluetooth in Settings.
3. Host room and wait people to join.
   After clicking home button you'll see at the top that people are paired.
4. Go to MCPE.
5. Launch server.
6. Wait a person to join.

See [This](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/minecraft-pocket-edition/mcpe-discussion/1964719-ios-minecraft-pe-how-to-multiplayer-in-bluetooth) for more