# Can I play multiplayer via Bluetooth?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Can I play Minecraft PE multiplayer without an Internet connection on either device? My brother and I have it on seperate devices, but we are not allowed to be on the Internet. Can we play via Bluetooth together? If so, how?

Comment: There is also [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/265515/149081) which propose an answer for iOS only